# retrieving response object of an url in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass parameters from one webpage to other,but it shud not be visible to the user. That is the parameters passing to the webpage should return the result that should displayed in my application without user knowing that we have visited that url webpage..please help

Comment: That sounds a little nefarious...  Why not use a stream or shared cookie?

Comment: Please clarify the overall scenario.

Comment: Sounds like a simple AJAX request to me..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead what does the OP actually want to do?

Comment: @Aniket I interpreted it as an AJAX request for, say, a JSON object and to display the results to the user.. an asynchronous request..

Answer (score 0):

why not use `Session`? Its not visible to the user and is pretty easy to use.

Comment: But my webpage is retrieving response from other webpage that belongs to a different website

Comment: That is a key detail to clarify in your question.

Comment: @user2011360 I am not certain what you want to do. The answer I've written is for the first sentence in your question. I don't understand the rest of the question, nor your comment on my answer.

Comment: @user704808 did you understand the OP's question?

Comment: i can give you one example..suppose u r designing an app dat searches information similar to google. bt internally you are sending that information as parameter to google and you are showing those results (given by google) to ur user.. bt user shud nt be aware of dat

Comment: @user2011360 There are API's for that specific scenario.. what is **YOUR** specific scenario?

Comment: its the same.. that i have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain I understand the question, but it sounds like the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok. I will try it out. Bt how shud i send request so that the other webpage gets its i/p